# MYSQLi Select - PHP echo every query term occurrence within row

Tags: php, select, mysqli

I have a table called `pages` that stores the id, url address, title, and content of webpages on my site. Here's an example of the table:

```
 ID |         address       |  title  |                      content               |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1  | www.example.com/page1 | Page 1  | The quick dog jumps over the lazy dog.     |
 2  | www.example.com/page2 | Page 2  | The best thing about morning is breakfast. |
 3  | www.example.com/page3 | Page 3  | Hotdogs are great ballpark food.           |
```

I would like to `SELECT` all occurrences of a query term, and echo them in `PHP`. For example, if I want to display search results for the word "**dog**" my `SELECT` statement would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM pages WHERE (`content` LIKE '%dog%')
```

and my full `PHP` statement with the search term = `$query` looks like this:

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE (`content` LIKE '%".$query."%')")) { 
  // if one or more rows are returned do following
  while($results = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
// $results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results) puts data from database into array, while it's valid it does the loop
  $content = $results['content'];
  $contentItems = $results['contentSearch'];

  // Count number of times term in content
  $count = substr_count($contentItems, $originalQuery);



  $content = substr($content,strpos($content,$firstTerm)-25,160);
  $content = (strlen($content) > 55 ? '...'.$content.'...' : substr($results['description'],0,160).'...');

  foreach($querySplit as $term){
    $content = str_ireplace($term, '<strong>'.$term.'</strong>', $content);
  }
  // highlight search terms

  $chars = array("\'", "&amp;");
  $charReplace = array("'", "&");
  $content = str_replace($chars,$charReplace,$content);

  // set $image if not empty
  $image = (!empty($results['image']) ? 'http://www.example.com/'.$results['image'] : '');


  /* ------------------
  ------ echo statement
  --------------------*/
  echo '
  <li class="media">';
// if image is not empty
if(!empty($image)): 
echo '<a class="pull-left span2 hidden-phone" href="http://www.example.com/'.$results['address'].'"> <img class="media-object thumbnail" src="'.$image.'" alt="'.$results['description'].'"/> </a>';
endif;
echo '
<div class="media-body">
      <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="http://www.example.com/'.$results['address'].'">'.htmlspecialchars_decode($results['title']).'</a></h4>
      <p class="result-address"><small><a href="http://www.example.com/'.$results['address'].'">http://www.example.com/'.$results['address'].'</a></small></p>
      ';
      /*if(!empty($image)): 
      echo '<a class="visible-phone" href="'.$results['address'].'"> <img class="thumbnail phone-search-thumb" src="'.$image.'" alt="'.$results['description'].'"/> </a>';
      endif;*/
      echo '
      <p class="result-content">'.$content.'</p>
    </div>
</li>
  ';
  /* ------------------
  ---end echo statement
  --------------------*/


} $result->close();
}
```

This `PHP` and `SELECT` statement returns two results:

1. The quick **dog** jumps over the...
2. Hot **dogs** are great...

**DESIRED RESULT (please help)**

What I would ***prefer***, is for my statement to `echo` one result for **every occurrence** of the `$query` term, even within the same row, as shown here:

1. The quick **dog** jumps over the... (from `Row 1`)
2. ...over the lazy **dog**. (from `Row 1`)
3. Hot **dogs** are great... (from `Row 3`)

**QUESTION**

How can I edit my `PHP` and/or my `SELECT` statement so that I may `echo` one result for ***every*** occurrence of the `$query` term?

Comment: Parse the `content` from database by `PHP` and see how many **dog** present in that sentence.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar - can you explain what you mean? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: Side-note, you should be using a prepared statement when querying the db with user-input. Also, you're mixing OOP and procedural-style mysqli. Is that present only in your example, or literally in your code?

Comment: @newfurniturey - I'm cleaning the user input before it goes to the DB. Left this out for simplicity.

Comment: You shouldn't clean anything but use prepared statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your answer.

```
<?php

$query="dog";

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE (`content` LIKE '%".$query."%')"))
{ 
    $inc = 0;
    $mysql_result = array();
    // if one or more rows are returned do following
    while($a_result = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        $mysql_result[$inc]=$a_result;
        $inc++;
    }

    $chars_to_show_before = 10;  // ...1234567890dog
    $chars_to_show_after = 10;  // dog1234567890...

    foreach($mysql_result as $results)
    {

        $content = str_replace($query,"my_un1qu3_r3pl4c3m3nt_".$query,$results['content']);

        $occurences = explode("my_un1qu3_r3pl4c3m3nt_",$content);

        $position_in_original_content = 0;

        foreach($occurences as $an_occurence)
        {

            if (strpos($an_occurence,$query) !== false)
            { 
                $content=$an_occurence;

                echo '<li class="media">
        <a class="pull-left" href="'.$results['address'].'">
        <img class="media-object thumbnail" src="'.$results['image'].'" style="height:100px !important">
        </a>
        <div class="media-body">
          <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="'.$results['address'].'">'.$results['title'].'</a></h4>
          <p>...'.str_replace($query,'<strong>'.$query.'</strong>', substr($results['content'],max(0,($position_in_original_content-$chars_to_show_before)),strlen(strlen($query))+$chars_to_show_after+$chars_to_show_before)).'...</p>
        </div>
       </li>';
            }

            $position_in_original_content = $position_in_original_content + strlen($an_occurence);

         }
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Sorry, no results found!";
}
?>
```

working demo here: http://3v4l.org/BTeCU

Comment: Forgive me if I'm misunderstanding this, but how would I initialize my results using my existing `mysqli` query so that the results are `$mysql_result[0]['address']="www.example.com/page1";` ?

Comment: @AdamD see updated answer (havent tested this but it should be ok) :)

Comment: It partially works with my code, but if the user has a compound term, like "dog park", it returns no results. I'm playing with it...

Comment: @AdamD make sure DB returns results on that occasion. do a `echo "<pre>".print_r($mysql_result,true)."</pre>";` after the `while { ... }` to see if you actually getting data from DB

Answer (score 0):

as Yogesh Suthar said: use PHP.

here quick and dirty example

```
$count = substr_count($content, 'dog');

$offset = 0;

for( $i = 0 ; $i < $count ; $i++ ) {

    echo $content; // put you code here with strpos($content,$query,$offset)

    $offset = strpos($content, 'dog', $offset) + strlen('dog');
}
```

**Edit:**

I add `$offset`

**Edit:**

```
while($results = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

    $content = $results['content'];

    $full_content = $content;

    $contentItems = $results['contentSearch'];

    // Count number of times term in content
    $count = substr_count($contentItems, $full_content);

    $offset = 0;

    for( $i = 0 ; $i < $count ; $i++ ) {

        $content = substr($full_content, strpos($full_content, $firstTerm, $offset )-25,160);


        // rest of your code

        /* ------------------
        ---end echo statement
        --------------------*/

        $offset = strpos($full_content, 'dog', $offset) + strlen('dog');
    }
}

$result->close();
```

Comment: This just shows the same result with highlight over and over and over for the number = `$count`. I need to move to the next occurrence of the term in the for each.

Comment: You can use 3th argument in [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to search next 'dog' in string.

Comment: See example now - I add `$offset`. Use `$offset` as 3th argument in `strpos()` in your code.

Comment: With the updated code above, `$offset` is not actually doing anything, is it?

Comment: There is `strpos($content,$query)` in your code. It seach first `dog` and always start from begining of `$content`. Use 3th argument in `strpos()` to change it - use `strpos($content,$query,$offset)`. And use my `$offset = ...` to calculate new offset.

Comment: I updated my code above after modifying all of my echo statements. Where would I put your code using the `$offset`? (Keep in mind, a portion of the code changed so your code may need to be altered)

Comment: You made so many modifications and you change `$content` in code so I add `$full_content`